# JSON Data Fetch and Print without .php extension

Tags: php, apache

I want to achieve reading and printing the JSON data without .php URL extension. But the server is returning an error.

**My PHP code (data.php) is as follows:**

```
    <?php

// GET FULL PAGE URL
$link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// GET EVRYHING AFTER THE LAST SLASH
$params = substr($link, strrpos($link, '/') + 1);

// PASS THE PARAMETERS TO API
$url = "http://api.plos.org/$params";

//read json file from url in php

$readJSONFile = file_get_contents($url);
header('Content-Type: application/json'); //
print_r($readJSONFile); // display contents
```

**.htaccess file for .php extension removal**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

I'm getting the correct data if I access with the .php extension (https://local.test/data.php/search?q=title:DNA) when I was trying without the .php extension it was returning a 404 error.
https://local.test/data/search?q=title:DNA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to change `.htaccess` file content with:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^data/search$ data.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1.php  [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you it worked!
 I have dynamic parameters (DNA&07APR2022&2022-03-30&17500)

domain.com/api/chart.php/DNA&07APR2022&2022-03-30&17500.

How can I achieve this without .PHP? 

Thanks again

Comment: Maybe you can try `RewriteRule ^api/chart/([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)$ api/chart.php chart.php?id=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3&param4=$4 [L]` so url will be `domain.com/api/chart/DNA/07APR2022/2022-03-30/17500`

Comment: Thanks for your response. It was throwing an Internal Server Error

Comment: This is how my .htaccess file like: 
    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^api/chart/([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)$ api/chart.php chart.php?id=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3&param4=$4 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1.php  [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]

Comment: `RewriteRule ^api/chart/([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)$ api/chart.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3&param4=$4 [L]`

Comment: this can work properly